# Python Concatenate Neighboring String Elements in List

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

Is there an elegant way (most likely using a list comprehension) to concatenate all neighboring string elements in an list?

I have a list where there is no functional difference between multiple strings in a row and all of those strings concatenated into a single string, but both for readability and for equivalence testing, I would like to concatenate these together. There can be other non-string elements in the list that can break up the strings. These need to remain between the concatenated groups of strings.

For example, I could have

```
rule = ["a", "b", C(), "d", "ef", "g"]
```

and instead, I want

```
rule = ["ab", C(), "defg"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is the usual answer for combining elements based on a common characteristic. In this case, we group on the type of the element, and when the type is `str`, we collapse it, otherwise we produce results from the group directly. As a "one-liner", you could do:

```
rule = ["a", "b", C(), "d", "ef", "g"]
rule = [x for cls, grp in itertools.groupby(rule, type)
          for x in ((''.join(grp),) if cls is str else grp)]
```

Assuming `C` is a class with a default `__repr__`, you'd get output that looks like this:

```
['ab', <__main__.C at 0x1d572c98588>, 'defg']
```

In this case, the "outer" loop of the listcomp is producing the shared type and an iterator of the elements with that type. When the type is `str`, we make a one-element `tuple` of the combined string to "iterate" (it's only one element, so we only iterate once); when it's not `str`, we produce the elements of the group one by one without further processing.

Comment: I was going to add an alternative approach with `chain.from_iterable`, but [Igor has that covered, so I'll just refer you to his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47168943/364696). Perf-wise, the listcomp is *probably* a little faster (if the inner genexpr could be expressed as a C level built-in, the `chain` approach would win by avoiding all byte code execution), but this is going to vary from version to version and between different Python interpreter lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this using `itertools.groupby` and `chain`.

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
isstr = lambda x: isinstance(x, basestring)
# on Python 3: lambda x: isinstance(x, str)

rule = ["a", "b", C(), "d", "ef", "g"]
list(chain.from_iterable(
    # join string groups into single-element sequence,
    # otherwise just chain the group itself
    (''.join(group), ) if group_isstr else group
    for group_isstr, group in groupby(rule, isstr)
))
```

```
['ab', <__main__.C object at 0x108dfdad0>, 'defg']
```

Comment: Minor fix: `t == str` should be `t is str` (or if you want to accept `str` subclasses, `issubclass(t, str)`). Classes are singletons (like `None`), so identity testing with `is`/`is not` is correct when you don't accept subclasses. Admittedly unlikely to encounter a type that violates the rule, but it's slightly more correct (and faster) to avoid invoking the rich comparison operations.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, good call, thanks! I edited with a slightly different approach (using `isinstance` in the key function, which also has the effect of joining `str` subclasses).

Comment: Ah. Note: On Py2, you can use `basestring` to test for both `str` and `unicode` at once (on Py3, there is only `str`). But good call on handling both on Py2 in the `key` function, where it would be weird not to collapse `str` and neighboring `unicode` instances; on Py3, using `type` as the `key` function works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
class C:
   pass
rule = ["a", "b", C(), "d", "ef", "g"]
s = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(rule, type)]
new_s = [''.join(b) if all(isinstance(c, str) for c in b) else b[0] for a, b in s]
```

Output:

```
['ab', <__main__.C instance at 0x101419998>, 'defg']
```

Comment: Why are you not taking advantage of your `a` (the result of using `type` as the `key` function)? Checking all the group members individually with `all`/`isinstance` when you *know* they have the same type is wasteful. And a bug: Using `b[0]` as your `else` case means you're going to drop data when you have two non-`str` in a row with the same type.

Answer (score 0):

In a basic way you can use this function:

```
def concat_str(lst):
    newlst = []
    newstr = ""
    length = len(lst)
    for index, elem in enumerate(lst):
        if(type(elem) is str):
            newstr = newstr + elem
            if(index == length -1):
                newlst.append(newstr)
        else:
            if(newstr):
                newlst.append(newstr)
            newlst.append(elem)
            newstr = ""
    return newlst
```

Comment: Naming quibble: Don't name a variable `empty_str` when it's not actually intended to be empty much of the time...

Comment: Just started to coding then forgot to change. Thanks :)

Comment: That's nicer. Though on rereading, you've got a bug here. Try it with an input with a pair of non-`str` items back-to-back in your input.